# Huge PostgreSQL table - Select, update very slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I have a table which is almost 20GB's. It has a primary key on the ID column which is an auto-increment column, however I am running my queries on another column which is a timestamp... I am trying to select/update/delete on the basis of a timestamp column but the queries are very slow. For example: A select on this table `where timestamp_column::date (current_date - INTERVAL '10 DAY')::date) is taking more than 15 mins or so..
Can you please help on what kind of Index should I add to this table (if needed) to make it perform faster?

Thanks

Comment: Follow the [info link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) in the postgresql-performance tag. Edit your question, and paste that info.

Comment: Did you create one index for the timestamp column?

Comment: You must show table definition, query and explain. For now, I'll advice you to avoid type cast or other data transformation on where clause (unless you have a index to it with proper expression): `timestamp_column::date`.

Comment: I do not have any index on the timestamp column.... the table definition is as follows: `Create Table Ns_Event
(
    Record_ID         bigserial,
    Event_ID          bigint not null,
    Type_ID           integer not null,   
    Position_ID                      integer null,
    Last_Updated        timestamptz,
    primary key (Record_ID)
);
` and the query that I am trying to run is `select * from ns_event where Last_Updated::date < (current_date - INTERVAL '25 DAY')::date`

Comment: Then you need to make one, like @michel.milezzi explained you should also either make it with explicit cast to date or don't use cast in WHERE. You could also consider using [partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Comment: Got it.. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an index with your clause expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ns_event_last_updated_idx ON ns_event (CAST(last_updated AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE));
```

But, keep in mind that you're using `timestamp with timezone`, cast this type to date can let you get undesirable side effects.

Also, remove all casting in your sql:

```
select * from ns_event where Last_Updated < (current_date - INTERVAL '25 DAY');
```